# Trying to Make Pop-Up Window/Overlay in Android Studio (Java)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-activity

I am trying to create a pop-up window/overlay in Android Studio with 2 activities. When a certain button (the green plus button in the first picture below) is pressed, it will start a second activity at a smaller size with a different layout (.xml) file. When the second activity is declared in the AndroidManifest.xml, it uses a custom theme I have created to make the first activity appear under it, however, it is not working properly.

Here are pictures of both activites:

First Activity -

[image]

Second Activity -

[image]

Here is the code:

MainActivity -

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        Util.initScreenRes(this);    // initializes screen resolution for later pop-up window sizing

    }

    public void ibAddOnClick(View view){
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddPopUpActivity.class));
    }

}
```

AddPopUpActivity -

```
public class AddPopUpActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_popup_activity);
        getWindow().setLayout((int) (Util.screenRes.x * 0.8), (int) (Util.screenRes.y * 0.5));
    }

}
```

Util -

```
public class Util {

    public static Point screenRes;

    public static void initScreenRes(Activity a){
        final DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        a.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        screenRes = new Point(dm.widthPixels, dm.heightPixels);
    }

}
```

Lastly, here is the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="App.ProgressTracker">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ProgressTracker">
        <activity
            android:name="App.FrontEnd.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.ProgressTracker.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="App.FrontEnd.AddPopUpActivity"
            android:label="ProgressTracker"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.ProgressTracker.PopUp">
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

For reference, I have used this tutorial on YouTube for the way I went about this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fn5OlqQuOCk&ab_channel=FilipVujovic

I'd appreciate any help on this. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In the AndroidManifest.xml set the theme of the pop up activity to
`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"`